# cakephp login form not working

Tags: forms, cakephp, input, authentication, submit

I've made a login form and now I need to have the same code in one of my **Cakephp** project but it doesn't work..

```
<!-- LOGIN SECTION START -->
    <section id="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive">
                    <h1 class="text-center form-login-title">Log In</h1>    
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">   

                        <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>

                            <div class="form-group inner-icon right-icon"> <!--USER NAME-->
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>

                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name='username' placeholder="username"/>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group inner-icon right-icon"> <!--PASSWORD-->
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>

                                <input class="form-control" type="password" name='password' placeholder="password"/>

                            </div>

                            <?= $this->Form->end(__('Sign In')); ?> <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->

                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                            </div>
                    </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
                </div>    
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section>
<!-- LOGIN SECTION END -->
```

So with that snippet does not let me log in (the back end is not the problem)

Oh, and how can I change the submit button style ? I've tried `<?= $this->Form->end(__(Sign In), array('class'=>'btn-primary')); ?>`
but it doesn't help much :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the CakePHP helpers, so instead plain HTML:

Change this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name='username' placeholder="username"/>
```

Into this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'username',
    'label' => false
));
?>
```

And this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" name='password' placeholder="password"/>
```

Into this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
    'type' => 'password',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'password',
    'label' => false
)); ?>
```

CakePHP Helper will print the input fields with the correct name values for each one, so in your controller you receive the correct data through the array $this->request->data.

For the button style try:

```
<?=$this->Form->end('Sign In', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger'))?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Ricardo mentioned,use CakePHP syntax and conventions.

Also it will be more helpful if you provide your controller actions. Probably your action is wrong.

For more things about forms and auth here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html